# How does conductivity $\sigma$ of salt-water depend on salinity?

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemical-engineering, current

In what way does the electrical conductivity $\sigma$ (or conversely, resistivity $\rho = 1/\sigma$) depend on the salinity $S$ of the saline- (or sea-) water?

I know they must be in some way proportional since the more free charge carriers (ions in this case) available, the more electric current is possible.

Answer (score 5):

Measuring the conductivity of water is actually one of the standard ways of measuring its salinity.  The figure below (taken from [this University of British Columbia page](http://www.eos.ubc.ca/ubcgif/iag/foundations/properties/resistivity.htm)) shows that the relationship over many orders of magnitude is 
$$
\sigma\propto S,
$$
where $\sigma$ is the conductivity and $S$ is the salinity.  They further note that the conductivity also varies with temperature and the relationship is given approximately by 
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma(T)}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sigma_{18 ^\circ C}}}{1+0.025(T-18\ ^\circ C)}.
$$

[image]

Fondriest has a [long tutorial on environmental conductivity measurements](http://www.fondriest.com/environmental-measurements/parameters/water-quality/conductivity-salinity-tds/) which is very informative.  It does an excellent job of explaining the environmental factors which affect water salinity and therefore measurements of water conductivity.